# Creating an (Lambda) Expression using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I have the following dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> filterProperties;
```

The content of this dictionary can be like this:

```
- "Language": [QueryData.Lang],
- "Id": [Querydata.UserId]
```

Each string key maps to a property of a my `QueryData` type.

Now let's suppose I have the following `QueryData` instance:

```
QueryData: { Lang= "en", UserId = "mcicero" }
```

Using the previous dictionary as example, I want to build the following expression:

```
e => e.Language == "en" && e.Id == "mcicero";
```

As you can see the dictionary keys are used for accesing the properties of `e`, and the dictionary values (QueryData properties) are used for specifying constants in the binary equal expressions.

`e` is of type `Entity`, and is guaranteed to have this properties.

The resulting expression should be of type `Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>`

How can I build this expression using recursion?

I say recursion because it sounds like a natural solution, but an iterative one would be preferred.

I tried the iterative alternative and ended up with an ugly and not so understandable code.

However, I am having trouble creating a recursion method for this problem.

Comment: you probably want to use dynamic linq. here's some info http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: You will probably need to look into [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

Comment: Ignoring all the dictionary and QueryData stuff, you just want to know how to create an Expression like `e => e.Language = "en"` at runtime from a `PropertyInfo` and a string.

Comment: Can you explain it better, what you mean with build this expression ?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Actually, I know how to create such expression, but I do not know how to join each mapped expression with an AND (&&) expression. The dictionary size can be variable

Comment: So is it "how to combine expressions with AND"? Sorry to be that picky, but the simpler the questions the better the answer and the more interesting for future readers ... I do not answer many questions because it takes me too much time already to read it ...

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I understand your concern and it didn't cross my mind. I will try to be more direct next time, thank you for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving the creation of the individual expression to you, simply combine them together in an iterative loop:

```
// For an IEnumerable<Expression> in "expressions"
Expression left = null;
foreach(var right in expressions)
{
  if(left == null)
    left = right;
  else
    left = Expression.And(left, right);
}
// Combined expression is in "left"
// Don't forget it will be null if there were no expressions provided...
```

Or in one line with LINQ:

```
var expr = expressions.Aggregate(Expression.And);
```

Comment: Thank you for that one line LINQ statement! Beautiful!

Comment: This &ing will result in a tree that is as deep as possible, which will reduce performance when there is a lot of nodes. You should try to build a tree as flat as possible, for example by putting them in a queue, taking out the first 2 elements, &ing them and putting at the end, until there is only 1 node left.

Answer (score 2):

For the interested ones, in one single line:

```
Expression expr = filterProperties.Select(i => Expression.Equal(
                                                  Expression.Property(entityParameter, i.Key),
                                                  Expression.Constant(i.Value.GetValue(queryObj))
                                         )).Aggregate(Expression.And);
```